# Overloading a struct constructor

Tags: racket

Is there a way to overload the constructor for a struct in Racket, so I can make the inherited parameters optional ?

In my case, I want to define some custom exceptions for my app.
For example :

```
(struct exn:my-app exn ())
(struct exn:my-app:illegal-access exn:my-app ())
```

However, to instantiate an illegal-access exception, I have to call the constructor with the 2 arguments inherited from exn (message and continuation-marks), which is quite cumbersome.

Is it possible to define (for exn:my-app and all its descendants) a constructor, which could make both parameters optional ? So I could call either :

```
(raise (exn:my-app:illegal-access))
(raise (exn:my-app:illegal-access "Message")) ?
```

Thanks,

Comment: Scheme doesn't have overloading of the sort you're thinking of, but it does have optional parameters, and it does have `case-lambda` (though not sure if you can use that for structs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
(struct exn:my-app exn ()
        ;; change the name of the constructor
        #:constructor-name make-exn:my-app)

;; custom constructor
(define (exn:my-app [msg "default msg"]
                    [marks (current-continuation-marks)])
  (make-exn:my-app msg marks))

(exn:my-app) ; this works now
```

Since you need to do this for each structure type, you may want to define a macro that abstracts over this. I bet someone has already shared such a macro on the Racket mailing list, but I don't recall one off the top of my head so I'll update this answer if I find a reference.

Comment: Good point! Well, finally I ended to define a custom raise method, taking the exception and 2 custom params ; it's less work. ;) Thanks!

Comment: As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131934/overloading-a-struct-constructor) points out, if I run this example now, I get an error message: `. module: duplicate definition for identifier in: exn:my-app`