# Overloading a struct constructor?

Tags: racket

My question is the same as the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288358/overloading-a-struct-constructor), but the answer given there doesn't actually work.

I have a bunch of structs inheriting from a parent struct `A`, which has two fields that I want to make optional for all its descendants. Previously I was using `#:auto`, but that turns out to really not be what I want because it breaks methods like `struct-copy`, and also I do want to be able to optionally supply values for those fields on struct creation.

I've found a few other questions about optional arguments for structs, but the answers have all suggested defining a custom constructor and using that instead. Unfortunately I already have a lot of code using the regular constructors, so what I really want is for this custom constructor to have the same name as the struct itself. The answer to the question I linked was what I was looking for, but unfortunately it only works in the REPL because there duplicate definitions are allowed. Outside of the REPL I get an error like `module: duplicate definition for identifier in: exn:my-app`, for example (when running the answer to the linked question).

edit: I know the duplicate definition problem is because the struct id is also bound to a transformer. I don't want to stop that definition from happening; I want a name bound to both a constructor and a transformer for that struct, where the constructor is not the default one.

Is there a way to do this that will play nicely with existing code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking further into the new struct keywords that [soegaard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23567/soegaard) mentioned, I think I've come up with a solution that's a bit cleaner and, more importantly, much easier to abstract into a macro (those modules and requires were giving me a really hard time). I thought I'd share it for future reference. Again, this requires one of the nightly Racket builds. I'm using 6.5.0.7.

(Note: the use of `case-lambda` over defining keyword arguments here is just my preference.)

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax syntax/transformer))

(struct horse (color)
  #:name Horse
  #:constructor-name Horse
  #:transparent)

(define make-horse
  (case-lambda
    [() (Horse "black")]
    [(color) (Horse color)]))

(define-match-expander horse
  ; match expander
  (λ (pat)
    (syntax-case pat ()
      [(_ more ...) #'(Horse more ...)]))

  ; constructor
  ; edit: changing this to use make-variable-like-transformer,
  ;  as suggested in the comments.
  #;(syntax-id-rules ()
      [(_ args ...) (make-horse args ...)]
      [horse Horse])
  (make-variable-like-transformer #'make-horse))
```

Sample usage:

```
> (define black-beauty (horse))
> black-beauty
(horse "black")

> (define ginger (horse "red"))
> ginger
(horse "red")

> (match black-beauty
    [(horse color) color])
"black"

> (match ginger
    [(horse color) color])
"red"

> (horse-color black-beauty)
"black"

> (horse-color ginger)
"red"
```

In short: instantiation, matching, and accessing fields seem to work as you would expect if you'd just used `struct`. The struct id can also be used as an identifier without any syntax issues. I don't really think that part has much practical use, but I thought it was nice.

Comment: A much nicer solution!

Comment: Just to make this solution a little nicer, the `(syntax-id-rules () [(_ args ...) (f arg ...)] [_ f])` pattern is handled by the [`make-variable-like-transformer`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/transformer-helpers.html#%28def._%28%28lib._syntax%2Ftransformer..rkt%29._make-variable-like-transformer%29%29) function from `syntax/transformer`. You can use it like `(make-variable-like-transformer #'make-horse)`. This also avoids a `set!` bug that your `syntax-id-rules` form has.

Answer (score 3):

The `struct` construct will define two entities with the name of the struct. A constructor and a transformer binding that has information on the struct.

In order to avoid the "duplicate identifier" error you can use `#:omit-define-syntaxes`.

An alternative is to define the struct in a submodule and export only the things you need (and possibly renaming some of the identifiers).

```
#lang racket
(struct horse (color)
  #:constructor-name make-horse
  #:omit-define-syntaxes
  #:transparent)

(define (horse #:color [color "black"])
  (make-horse color))

(horse)
(horse #:color "red")
```

Output:

```
(horse "black")
(horse "red")
```

EDIT

A solution that works with match is possible with the help of a match expander.
Note: You need at least version 6.5 for this to work due the the use of `#:extra-name`.

```
#lang racket

(module horse racket
  (provide (struct-out Horse)
           make-horse)
  (struct horse (color)
    #:extra-name Horse
    #:extra-constructor-name make-horse
    #:transparent))

(require 'horse)

; the custom horse constructor
(define (my-make-horse #:color [color "black"])
  (make-horse color))

(define-match-expander horse
  ; match expander
  (λ (pat)
    (syntax-case pat ()
      [(_horse more ...)
       #'(Horse more ...)]))
  ; constructor
  (λ (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_horse arg ...)
       (syntax/loc stx
         (my-make-horse arg ...))])))

(horse)
(horse #:color "red")

(match (horse #:color "blue")
  [(horse color) color])
```

Output:

```
(horse "black")
(horse "red")
"blue"
```

Comment: This works for overloading the constructor, but now I have a problem because I also need the transformer to be bound to the same name for matching. So I want to be able to have both the overloaded constructor and the transformer bound to the same name.

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising! Strangely, I'm having trouble with #:extra-name even though I do have Racket 6.5. I'll at least keep this in mind so I can fix the problem at some point. From the documentation I could find on #:extra-name, it looks like (struct-out Horse) will export horse-color and not Horse-color, since Horse is just bound to the struct information. Is that correct?

Comment: You might need one of the nightly builds then. See https://pre.racket-lang.org/installers/

Comment: Thanks! It works with 6.5.0.7. And to answer my own question that I edited in after commenting, it is horse-color and not Horse-color that's exported by struct-out. It also looks like I can actually use Horse as a constructor, so it's not necessary to use #:extra-constructor-name and then export that identifier.